# Symfony .. hyperlinks on a view

Tags: php, model-view-controller, symfony, twig

My question is how to make a hyperlink in a view? Like `<a href="link"></a>` in HTML. Have I to create it in an action method in the controller and then send it to a view? or what exactly?

Comment: @scube, ah I forgot that, I'm using PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Twig templating engine you would have something like

```
<a href="{{ path('homepage') }}">Home</a>
```

If you are using PHP for your templates you would have something like

```
<a href="<?php echo $view['router']->generate('homepage') ?>">Home</a>
```

*homepage* in the above examples is a route identifier that you must already have defined in your routing configuration

Comment: that did the purpose, I added a set of parameters:
`<a href="<?php echo $view['router']->generate('homepage',array("UID" => $uid)) ?>">Home</a>` and here we go, thanks ma friend!

Answer (score 1):

Define the anchor text in the view.

Views are exactly what they sound like they're for, providing view to the visitor. Controllers, models are all for the internal processing & logic of the application.

Comment: @Johnn, well, got it, but now what's the syntax for creating an anchor?